# Chi - the force of life

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

> Clicking the image might broaden your horizon.
>
> There's a tag which, if added, would give away where this puzzle leads

Comment: [tag:steganography] not needed?

Comment: +1 for the hilarious image. I'm intrigued... No idea what to do but... intrigued

Comment: Is it a painting?

Comment: Turn it sideways and everything is a bunch of text characters.

Comment: @pie314271 maybe some kind of esoteric programming language :O.

Comment: Looks kind of like those Asian smileys, but I have no idea what to do with them.

Comment: It *does* look like an esoteric programming language, but even if it was valid it's not complex enough to do anything

Comment: @somebody I wouldn't be too sure about that, I've see some pretty complex stuff over on Code Golf SE

Comment: @Areeb ... I don't mean the language, I mean the text in the image

Comment: Why don't you tell us the tag needed? Right now it's just a bunch of symbols composing a weird image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following a couple hints, we find:

> [image: x]
>  This is from taking the letters in the original image that stand out,
>  from left to right, as an imgur hash:  **Ooo0r**
>  (and also indicates the 'missing tag' is probably [imgur-maze](/questions/tagged/imgur-maze)).
>
>  Transcription:
>
> ```
>          Wfno htnf, ary outv
>           vsqvff wlj pvbcpj!
>            Npy js gadm dri
>            tfno iaesarrj :)
>
>     This may seem difficult but it
>              sure isn't.
>     Sometimes what you're looking
>     for is right under your nose.
> ```

The next step is obvious ...

> Decrypt the encrypted text.
>
>  The hint in the image that what we're looking for is right under our nose should suggest the keyboard, and did; but `keyboard`, `keys`, and a few other things didn't work.  I also tried `mouth` and `lips` and `mustache` and the like, similarly with no results.
>
>  It turns out that the color of the blue block under the word "nose" in the image is actually hex #abcdef - which, like your keyboard, has the letters of the alphabet in it.  @TechIdiot found the key  "abcdef" and, at some prompting from OP in The Sphinx's Lair that blind guessing (or brute-forcing) the key wasn't needed, spotted the #abcdef color in the image.
>
>  With the key in hand, we can now decrypt the message:
>  **Well done, you just solved the puzzle! Now go back and tell everyone :)**

So - Hey everyone, I have just solved the puzzle!

Answer (score 4):

is it

> a bad pun of "stick-up"?

it is simple but we were told

> to not overthink it

Comment: Possibly, but I think there's a significance to the Stick family as it appears to be mom (long hair), dad (mustache), and twin children (shorter).

Comment: Also, "real gun" may be a number pun?